# Fatal error: Call to undefined method User->get_fullname()

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have problem with get data from database. 
This is my function:

```
        public function get_fullname($uid) 
        {
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
            var_dump(mysql_result($result));
            if(mysql_result($result)>0){
                //$user_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                echo $user_data['name'];
            }
            else{
            print_r('chuj');
            }
        }
```

and this is my function call:

```
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];

$user = new User();
$register = $user->get_fullname($uid);
```

What is wrong with my code?

Full class in file Functions.php:

```
    include_once 'config.php';
    class User
    {
        //Połączenie z bazą danych
        public function __construct() 
        {
            $db = new DB_Class();
        }
        //Rejestracja
        public function register_user($name, $username, $password, $email) 
        {
            $password = md5($password);
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT uid from users WHERE username = '$username' or email = '$email'");
            $no_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
            if ($no_rows == 0) 
            {
                $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username, password, name, email) values ('$username', '$password','$name','$email')") or die(mysql_error());
                return $result;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        //Logowanie
        public function check_login($emailusername, $password) 
        {
            $password = md5($password);
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT uid from users WHERE email = '$emailusername' or username='$emailusername' and password = '$password'");
            $user_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $no_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if ($no_rows == 1) 
            {
                $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $user_data['uid'];
                var_dump($_SESSION);
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        //Pobieranie imienia
            public function get_fullname($uid) 
            {
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid ='".$uid."'");
                $user_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $no_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
                if($no_rows>0){
                    $user_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                    //echo $user_data['name'];
                    return $user_data['name'];
                }
                else{
                    print_r('chuj');
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }
        //Sesja
            public function get_session() 
            {
                return $_SESSION['login'];
            }
        //Wylogowanie
        public function user_logout() 
        {
            $_SESSION['login'] = FALSE;
            session_destroy();
        }

    }
```

?>
**Fatal error: Call to undefined method User->get_fullname()**

Comment: Please show us the full class definition

Comment: Ok, sorry I eddited my post

Comment: You don't return anything in this function, so how do you want to store this in a variable?

Comment: Do something like: `return $user_data['name'];` instead of `echo $user_data['name'];` also do `return 0;` in the else statement

Comment: Still I have this error, can u edit my function?
` public function get_fullname($uid) 
    {
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
     var_dump(mysql_result($result));
     if(mysql_result($result)>0){
      //$user_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      echo $user_data['name'];
      return $user_data['name'];
     }
     else{
     print_r('chuj');
     return FALSE;
     }
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rizier123's comment is correct, but not the cause of your problem.

I tried to reproduce the error but failed. That means that probably you're using an old version somewhere. If you're using FTP or the like, are you sure you uploaded the User class since you added the function?

Also, make sure that the most recent User class is included in the file where you're using it.

Comment: Yeah right, I worked on old version functions.php. Now i have Warning: mysql_result() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/krytykak/domains/krytyka-konstruktywna.pl/public_html/recenzje/include/functions.php on line 50

`code`$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE uid ='".$uid."'");

Comment: @Kubol You need to use `mysql_result()` according to its definition at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php: use `mysql_result($result, 0)` to get the first row, for example.

Comment: Now I don't have any errors, but $user = new User();

$konto = $user->get_fullname($uid);

var_dump($konto); show "NULL" Sorry for my stupid questions, but I want to learn it

Comment: @Kubol that's because the function doesn't return anything, check Rizier's comments for that. It may also be that the mysql query doesn't return anything.

Comment: I added "return $user_data['name'];" Look now on my funtions.php if u can :)

Comment: @Kubol you're fetching the data twice. The second time, there's no data to fetch anymore. Remove the first mysql_fetch_array.